# Serial voting reversed and recidivism prevention

Tags: discussion, serial-voting, ethics

I recently seen a message called serial voting reversed.

In my "reputation" in my user profile on Mi Yodeia, 
there was 62 downvotes canceled and 5 of my downvote canceled. There was also 8 upvotes on answer reversed and one upvote on question.

My question is if there is someone who likes downvoting my answers in a serial way, the statistical correction of stack exchange is retroactive only or is there a preventive measure against recidivism.

I searched and did not find an answer. Please help me to know.

I have a high presumption, based on the fact that the last downvote was on an answer in which the same user wrote a comment on an other answer to the same question at the same time. An additional reason is that the difficulty to lose a compulsory activity is great.

In the past ***it was very hard for me to be taken seriously by moderators.*** I feel that somewhat is not clear for me how can I require to get advocacy. I feel that for a lengt time  moderators refuted to help me. Is there something non appropriate in the moderation system?

Comment: You realize the same question also got migrated to the Meta of [Mi Yodeia](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4224/serial-voting-reversed-and-recidivism-prevention)?

Comment: @rene this migration is happened after that I realized that I posted my question in meta stackoverflow and not in meta exchange. If possible I prefer to post it in meta exchange. But if it's not right I will remove  it from here.

Comment: It can live here as well. The only thing is that the other post already had some valuable comments that almost answered the question.

Comment: I have included the issue of both comments. I did not find an answer regarding prevention.

Comment: Most should be answered [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me), I even thnk it is a full dupe. The last paragraph answers your recidivism question.

Comment: right that there is a kind of answer but how can it be a criterion if it is not automated @rene   BTW I removed the question from mi yodeia meta

Comment: @kouty I guess there wasn't much need to detect recidivism automatically as that get probably noticed and reported by the victims. That is where SE staff can investigate the patterns. That is hard to do for any (AI) algorithm and when it gets it wrong, who are you going to blame?

Comment: "I have a high presumption, based on the fact that the last downvote was on an answer in which the same user wrote a comment on an other answer to the same question at the same time. An additional reason is that the difficulty to lose a compulsory activity is great". This doesn't prove the person who commented left the downvote.  Please don't make this assumption

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only so much information about anti-recidivism practices is public. Publicizing the tools and methods moderators and automated scripts use to catch, revert, and act on long-term serial voting problems would be a... bad idea. So, a lot of the details for what you're asking about aren't details you're going to be able to find easily.

Questions like "how is serial voting detected?" or "what tools are available to moderators to detect voting issues?" are very likely to remain unanswered, no matter who and where you ask. Not many people know the answers to begin with. This includes questions such as whether Stack Exchange has any anti-recidivistic statistics in place.

The closest you're likely going to get is from [this FAQ question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me):

> Continual abuse of the system which causes multiple reversals can lead to a suspension, but the review process for such a suspension is completely manual. No automated flags are ever generated for this behavior, though moderators do have access to some statistics that can help fight repeat offenders. If you find you are the victim of serial voting multiple times within a short time span, feel free to flag one of your posts for moderator attention and explain the situation so they can investigate further.

Comment: you answered this knowing the topic or by guess.  (I am sorry,  I don't know you :-)). Additionally I added some details on the answer.

Comment: @kouty No worries! I'm a moderator on Stack Exchange, and I have experience using the tools that are available. That being said, I still won't talk about their details ;) As to your edit, it's extremely unlikely that the mod team ignored your flags. They were likely read and looked into. (Usually, we don't/can't update people as to the details of the outcome.) You're welcome to use the Contact Us link, though, if you feel it's not being looked into the way you'd like.